# Select distinct rows from a table with an inner join

Tags: sql, distinct

Hi am trying to build a query that currently looks like this:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT cit.ComputerName
    FROM ComputerInvTracking cit
         INNER JOIN (
               SELECT ComputerName, 
                      DATEDIFF(day, time, GetDate()) AS time,
                      REPLACE(REPLACE(room, ',OU=Rooms,OU=Computers,OU=student,DC=campus,DC=ads,DC=uwe,DC=ac,DC=uk',''), 'OU=CL_','') AS room
                 FROM ComputerInvTracking cit2
         )
               ON cit.ComputerName = cit2.ComputerName
ORDER BY cit2.time
```

It is currently complaining of a Syntax error near the close bracket. 
I am using SQL server

I am completely stuck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a table alias on the subquery.  All subquerys need to have names:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cit.ComputerName
FROM ComputerInvTracking cit INNER JOIN
     (SELECT ComputerName, DATEDIFF(day, time, GetDate()) AS time, REPLACE(REPLACE(room, ',OU=Rooms,OU=Computers,OU=student,DC=campus,DC=ads,DC=uwe,DC=ac,DC=uk',''), 'OU=CL_','') AS room
      FROM  ComputerInvTracking cit2
     ) cit2
     --^
     ON cit.ComputerName = cit2.ComputerName
ORDER BY cit2.time
```

Comment: Would you be able to help explain why when I run this query I only get the ComputerName field back, rather than the other fields as well? 
Where am I going wrong?!

Comment: @GiANTOnFire . . . You are selecting `cit.ComputerName`.  If you want other fields, put them in the `select` list.

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon Linoff mentioned, you need to alias your subqueries.  That is the cause of the Syntax error you are currently getting.

Looking at your query, it appears you are trying to get all of the unique `ComputerName`s in `ComputerInvTracking` and then track their history.  I think you have your query backwards, and actually want to do the "unique ComputerName" filtering in your subquery (or in a Common Table Expression).

The way your query works right now, you will first get NxN rows for each computer (where N is the number of entries in the `ComputerInvTracking` table for that computer's `ComputerName`), and then filter out the duplicates.  This is extra work, and it would remove rows where the same computer was in the same room multiple times within a day, since that would show as a duplicate row in your query.

I would recommend something similar to the following:

```
WITH
-- Get the unique computers from the tracking table
UniqueComputers AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ComputerName
    FROM ComputerInvTracking
)
-- Match up each tracking record with it's computer
SELECT HIS.ComputerName,
       DATEDIFF(day, time, GetDate()) AS time,
       REPLACE(REPLACE(HIS.room, ',OU=Rooms,OU=Computers,OU=student,DC=campus,DC=ads,DC=uwe,DC=ac,DC=uk',''), 'OU=CL_','') AS room
FROM   UniqueComputers CMP
INNER JOIN ComputerInvTracking HIS
    ON CMP.ComputerName = HIS.ComputerName
ORDER BY time
```